# Delete row (column A to K) if cell blank in column D (or filter and delete all (Blanks)

Tags: excel, vba

Looking for some help here since most answers delete the entire row. Thanks in advance!

This is what my table looks like, I'm looking to delete a row (but only from column A to K, not entire row), if a cell is blank in column D.

Data is dynamic, will change each time, but it should always have a blank in cell D. If not, looking for the code to just continue on.

**So highlighted D3 is blank, I want it to delete A3 to K3.**
[image]
.

.

**You could filter cell D2 for (Blanks) to have them all** -- mind you there most likely will be a blank cell in column B, but I essentially want to delete all this data filtered.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is is ColumnK or ColumnF. Something like this, maybe. Just change to suit your needs.

```
Option Explicit

Sub BlankRowDeletion()

'Declaring variables
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Rng As Range

'Getting row number of last cell
LastRow = Range("A3").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

'Selecting all data
Set Rng = Range("A3:K" & LastRow)

'Selecting Blank cells
Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select

'Deleting complete row
Selection.EntireRow.Delete

Range("A3").Select

End Sub
```